# Which Lie groups have finitely many conjugacy classes of subgroups of fixed isomorphism type?

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory, lie-groups

Let $G$ be a real Lie group.
What conditions must $G$ satisfy so that the following is true:

> For any finite group $\Gamma$ there exist finitely many conjugacy classes of subgroups of $G$ that are isomorphic to $\Gamma$.

I believe that for $G=GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ this is true because:
subgroups of $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ are conjugate if and only if the restriction of the standard representation of $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ to the subgroups are isomorphic representations.
Finite groups have finitely many irreducible representations, and that proves the claim.

I also believe that for $G=SO(n)$ this is true because of this answer: https://mathoverflow.net/a/17074/164084.

It would be enough for my application to know that every real, compact, connected Lie group that has a faithful representation has the property stated above ("For any finite group $\Gamma$...").

Comment: This got an answer on mathoverflow now: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/401775/which-lie-groups-have-finitely-many-conjugacy-classes-of-subgroups-of-fixed-isom